# Discolored Ground Meat

Tags: beef

Why can't the paper that covers the Ground Meat be changed to another kind of paper to prevent oxygen from permeating  the paper and causing the ground meat to turn grey inside or brown outside?  Appearance of the meat is very important to the consumer, while cooking and eating it!  It turns me off!

Comment: What "paper" are you referring too? Please describe or use pictures.

Comment: Ground meat turns most people off, you have no idea what's in there. Buy whole meat, and grind it yourself, safer and prettier

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this falls under the "rant disguised as question" category mentioned in the help center, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask (see the last bullet point on the types of question which are generally closed)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed something up. Ground meat exposed to Oxygen is red. From there on two effects will change the color of the meat.

The Oxygen is removed from the myoglobin and

- replaced with water (H2O): dark purple.
- also lost an electron: brown.

This is a biological process which can only be prevented by not creating ground meat. If you cut your apple into two halves, they turn brown - this is not really the fault of the fruit farmer.

If the color is important, you have to make ground meat yourself right before you need it.